# How do I add JSON Data into ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress, chart.js

Here is my app.js

```
app.js 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-         json/llama/v1/stats').then(function(response) {
var visitDates = response.data.visits.labels.map(function(dateString) {
return new Date(dateString);
});

$scope.visits = response.data.visits.datasets;

angular.forEach($scope.visits, function(dataSet) {
dataSet.data = dataSet.data.map(function(count, i) {
return {
  date: visitDates[i],
  count: count
 };
});
});
});
});
```

The Data coming in is for an Analytics Chart, wherein the datasets must show for each day of the week along side the "label".
I'm new to AngularJS, ChartJS and JSON, please suggest

Here is a working Plunkr for the Requested Data http://plnkr.co/edit/Pfxc4JrKhv9SNlRUWqHi?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this 
[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart)

Please provide a working plunker where you are receiving data for plotting graph.

Comment: [See this](http://plnkr.co/edit/0eHQPVRHmCWelK6VEYVE?p=preview) For more proper data on x axis use moment.js for date manipulation

Comment: But the Chart is not visible in it :?

Comment: Scroll down to see chart

Comment: Nope! It's a blank screen! :(

Comment: [Now] (http://plnkr.co/edit/0eHQPVRHmCWelK6VEYVE?p=preview)    Were you able to locate new code added, if yes then try it on your local environment

Comment: I checked the same code locally and the Console is showing this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: That's because you are hitting that URL from localhost, Access-Control-Allow-Origin request comes when requesting site is not secure. It has nothing to do with Chart.js

Comment: Yes, something was wrong from my side. checked the output on another machine and it works well. Also, for the various labels available, how do i add a drop down menu? As in, 'label1' 'label2' 'label3' coming down as drop down options on the top of the graph, when i select a label, the analytics for that are shown

Comment: As per my understanding, you are asking for black colored tooltips, I don't thinks so you can add a dropdown. For further queries refer official chart.js documentation

Comment: Hey! Have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lcGPGIluRidtUr8V6mIm?p=preview . How do populate the data into the chart, when the users selects a label from the dropdown? Please help

Comment: Create a closure for populating data for selected item from the dropdown.

Comment: Also, for the dates that are being shown, how do i customise it? I only wanted the Month and Day to be seen